# Sprite Kit - containsPoint for SKPhysicsBody?

Tags: collision-detection, ios, physics, spritekit

I have a ball bouncing around the screen. I can pick it up and drag it onto a "bucket".

When my touches finish, I use the containsPoint function to check and see if I have dropped the ball onto the bucket.

This works fine, however, I actually want to check whether the ball is dropped onto the bucket node's physics body because my "bucket" is actually just an oval, and so I've applied a physics body which is the same shape as the oval, so that the white space around the oval isn't included in the physics simulation.

I can't seem to find a "containsPoint" function for physics bodies. Can anyone advise on how I'd check for this?

To summarise, I want to drop a node, onto a specific part of another node (or its physics body) and trigger an event.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar question and I did use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25348387/1151916) solution.
Construct CGPathRef and then do check using CGPathContainsPoint in touchesBegan method.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest means of determining if there is contact after your touches finish is to alter the category of the "ball" to a category that registers contacts with the "bucket".

That is to say, your ball would have a category that ignores the bucket until the ball is dragged and the touches end (*touchesEnd* method), at which point the category of the *SKPhysicsBody* of the ball will be changed to a category that no longer ignores the bucket.  A simple *didBeginContact* method executes your desired behavior for the ball being dropped in the bucket.